# Moq - is it possible to return a mock from a mock?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Hi I am trying to unit test an Entity framework which contains an entity collection. Definitions like below:

```
public interface IRatesRepositoryEntities : IDisposable
{
    IObjectSet<StaticScenarioContainer> StaticScenarioContainers { get; }
}

public partial class StaticScenarioContainer : EntityObject
{
    public EntityCollection<StaticScenarioShockGroup> StaticScenarioShockGroups
}
```

I am able to mock `StaticScenarioContainers` using code below:

```
        var list = new[]
        {
            new StaticScenarioContainer
            {
                M_SCNLABEL = containerName
            }
        };
        var mockObjectSet = new FakeObjectSet<StaticScenarioContainer>(list);

        mockRatesRepositoryEntities.Setup(e => e.StaticScenarioContainers)
            .Returns(mockObjectSet);
```

`FakeObjectSet` implements `IObjectSet` and support `Linq` queries.

But when I am trying to mock `StaticScenarioShockGroup` from mocked `StaticScenarioContainers` code below failed. Please suggest:

```
        var mockStaticScenarioShockGroups = new EntityCollection<StaticScenarioShockGroup>();
        var mockStaticScenarioContainer = new Mock<StaticScenarioContainer>();
        mockStaticScenarioContainer.Setup(e => e.M_SCNLABEL).Returns(containerName);
        mockStaticScenarioContainer.Setup(e => e.StaticScenarioShockGroups)
            .Returns(mockStaticScenarioShockGroups);

        var list = new[]
        {
            mockStaticScenarioContainer.Object
        };
        var mockObjectSet = new FakeObjectSet<StaticScenarioContainer>(list);

        mockRatesRepositoryEntities.Setup(e => e.StaticScenarioContainers)
            .Returns(mockObjectSet);
```

Notice that `EntityCollection` is a sealed class thus cannot be extended.

Comment: Is having `StaticScenarioShockGroups` as a field a typo? to use it with moq it needs to be a public virtual property.

Comment: Could you please provide FakeObjectSet code? What do you mean by code failed? Compilation error, test execution failure?